# MapDB background compaction

Tags: key-value-store, mapdb

For one of our projects, I'm using MapDB as a persistent Key/Value store. I'm using HTreeMap backed by a file and would like to know how I can enable compaction in the background.

```
final DB mapDB = DBMaker.fileDB(...).transactionEnable().executorEnable().closeOnJvmShutdown().make();
final HTreeMap<> itemsMap = mapDB.hashMap(..., Serializer.STRING,
        custom_serializer).expireExecutor(
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3)).expireCompactThreshold(
                0.4).counterEnable().createOrOpen();
```

The code is not exactly same as above, but similar. Can someone let me know what I'm missing? I don't see the file getting compacted at all. What is that I'm missing?

Regards,
-C

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code where the scheduler is getting initialized in HTreeMap class, the background compaction is scheduled only if both the below conditions are true

1. A ScheduledExecutorService is configured
2. Either of expireAfterUpdate, expireAfterDelete or expireAfterCreate is enabled
   https://github.com/gigliovale/-mapdb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mapdb/HTreeMap.kt#L145

Configuring #2 could have side effects and this makes your HTreeMap more like a cache. If you want to avoid that, you need to set the ttl to Long.MAX_VALUE

An alternate approach here would be to have your own scheduler, which can trigger compaction using the HTreeMap API, which internally checks the configured threshold and does compaction. Please note that this call blocks the HTreeMap segment for writes

```
itemsMap.expireEvict()
```